# Can not find name 'routes' in routeModule

Tags: angular, typescript-typings

imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: ‘reload’})],
I am getting error on variable  'can not find name routes'

I have import in app.module.ts
import { Routes, RouterModule, ExtraOptions } from '@angular/router';

angular version 14

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxDeS.png)

I have tried to import required modules but did not work.

Comment: If you check the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#defining-a-basic-route) you see -just after the imports zone- `const routes: Routes = [...];`. Is in this "const" where you define the "routes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have a routes list for your existing component that you need to navigate in your app-routing.module.ts. for example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'logout',  component: LogoutComponent },
  { path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', component: MainComponent},
];
```